# Why are we still using Continuous Time Fourier Transform when we have Laplace Transform?

Tags: fourier-transform, laplace-transform

I've read that **Laplace Transform** is more versatile and can cover a broad range of signals compared to **Continuous Time Fourier Transform**. Then why are we still using **Continuous Time Fourier Transform** ?

Comment: What you heard is not entirely correct. Read [this answer](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/26178/4298). There are also many related posts over at math.SE.

Comment: Note that the Laplace transform of $\sin(\omega_0t)$, $-\infty<t<\infty$ doesn't exist. Also the impulse responses of ideal brickwall filters (ideal low pass, high pass, etc.)  have no Laplace transform, while they do have a Fourier transform.