# How do I make sense of the cosine wave having Fourier Transform coefficients which have infinite magnitude?

Tags: fourier-transform, frequency-spectrum

To illustrate my question better, consider the Fourier Transform of an aperiodic (as a periodic cosine wave has a Fourier Transform not Fourier Series) cosine wave

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
\cos(2\pi f_0x),  & \text{$ 0 \le x \le 2\pi$} \\
0, & \text{else}
\end{cases}$$

$$F[f(x)] = \frac{1}{2}(\delta(f - f_0) + \delta(f + f_0)) $$

This above implies an aperiodic cosine wave consists of two Fourier Transform coefficients which have infinite magnitude (as a delta function has infinite magnitude). Therefore, does this imply that a perfect cosine wave can not be produced in real life?

Comment: (1) I don't think your FT is correct. (2) Regardless, a pure cosine wave cannot be produced in real life: you'd have to have turned your source on before the universe even began! Not to mention the need for an infinite amount of energy.

Comment: @MBaz I often see questions stating "The Fourier Transform of a cosine wave", I thought they couldn't possibly be referring to a periodic cosine wave, so it shouldn't it be an aperiodic wave like I've shown?

Comment: Please see this question and answers for a hint: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/6038/41790

Comment: @vecohah Mathematically it _is_ possible to find the FT of a periodic cosine wave, but you get Dirac deltas. The FT of the truncated cosine doesn't have any deltas.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is both integrable, and square integrable, because it is continuous on the finite support $[0\;2\pi]$. In this context ($L_1 \cap L_2$), its Fourier transform is pretty well defined as a classical function (not a distribution like the Dirac), and continuous. So, your formula is incorrect.

So there is no *infinite magnitude*. Moreover, one cannot simply say that Dirac have "infinite magnitude".

Yet, this would not imply that *a perfect cosine wave can not be produced in real life*; produced by whom? However, there is little chance that somebody could observe, or capture, a perfect cosine wave in real life (*caveat*: if real life can be described by a continuous time variable, and amplitude could be continuous as well).